# Re-order and re-id existing records into a new table of same structure

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, indexing

I have a table named `"table_name"` with several columns, including `id` (type=INT, autoincrement, primary) and `date` (type=datetime formatted Y-m-d h:m:s).

The id don't match the chronological order of the datetime column, because once the table was merged with another table. I don't mind having gaps in the id count, but I'd like to have it at least chronological based on the column "date".

In case that might help, I have already prepared an empty table with the exact same format as the original reference table, named let's say `"table_name_new"`.

So how is it possible to achieve the reassigning of the index id values?

PHP or SQL, both are welcome.

**Current state (example):**

```
+----+--------+---------------------+
| id | color  | date                |
+----+--------+---------------------+
| 1  | blue   | 2019-05-06 20:30:00 |
| 2  | orange | 2019-05-12 10:30:00 |
| 8  | yellow | 2019-05-18 22:30:00 |
| 4  | white  | 2019-05-29 12:30:00 |
| 9  | black  | 2019-06-10 09:30:00 |
| 10 | green  | 2019-06-14 08:30:00 |
| 3  | red    | 2019-06-24 17:30:00 |
| 5  | purple | 2019-07-05 10:30:00 |
| 7  | brown  | 2019-08-09 19:30:00 |
| 6  | grey   | 2019-09-12 20:30:00 |
+----+--------+---------------------+
```

**Desired result:**

```
+----+--------+---------------------+
| id | color  | date                |
+----+--------+---------------------+
| 1  | blue   | 2019-05-06 20:30:00 |
| 2  | orange | 2019-05-12 10:30:00 |
| 3  | yellow | 2019-05-18 22:30:00 |
| 4  | white  | 2019-05-29 12:30:00 |
| 5  | black  | 2019-06-10 09:30:00 |
| 6  | green  | 2019-06-14 08:30:00 |
| 7  | red    | 2019-06-24 17:30:00 |
| 8  | purple | 2019-07-05 10:30:00 |
| 9  | brown  | 2019-08-09 19:30:00 |
| 10 | grey   | 2019-09-12 20:30:00 |
+----+--------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Do you need to retain anything other than the colors? If not, export the data as `INSERT` queries and replace `id` with `NULL` and the date as `NOW`.

Comment: `I don't mind having gaps in the id count, but I'd like to have it at least chronological based on the column "date".` Why?

Comment: @Daniel Do you have these id(s) used anywhere else in other tables as well ? (like a Foreign Key)..if yes, then this isn't really a good idea to rearrange id values.

Comment: From what you wrote, there's no real reason why you want to tamper with synthetic primary key except personal OCD. If you do nothing, everything works. If you tamper with it, stuff dies. How about you do nothing? In 100 cases out of 100, trying to "force" auto_increment to re-use numbers or don't have gaps results in catastrophe. Why don't you add an additional column, call it `number_to_satisfy_my_ocd`, and maintain its value sequentially? You're using the wrong column to play with - `auto_increment` is not for humans to touch.

Comment: The feature is available in the deprecated MyISAM, but not in InnoDB.  See also:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb#index_issue_2_column_pk

Comment: To answer your questions: the ids of the table are not used anywhere else, so dont panic. The reason is for estethics, and for having a chronological table select, in case I miss to add "ORDER BY date" in my PHP selections. I appricate your careness. I used the solution of Koala Yeungs answer by considering the additional infos of my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Query

The query that you asked for is:

```sql
INSERT INTO `table_name_new` (`color`, `date`)
  SELECT `color`, `date` FROM `table_name` ORDER BY `date`;
```

Further documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html) describes other variations of similar operation in MySQL.

But as many comments stated, it is **not recommended** to mess with `id` after they are defined. Some other part of your code might expect the `id` to have a certain meaning. Plus it is pretty trivial to re-order your records with `ORDER BY` clause when needed.

So unless you're sure that `id` is absolutely trivial / meaningless in your entire code base, you're advised against this kind of operation.

Please consider carefully.

### How to prevent manually building column list to just omit 1 column?

Unfortunately, there is no MySQL syntax that directly support selecting table columns by defining which to omit. We may, however, build our own SQL query to run by other MySQL queries.

Assuming,

1. you have the right permission; and
2. you are already in the correct database;

then,

```sql
--
-- Build a comma separated column list (omitting "`id`," and ",`id`")
-- as session variable "@columns"
--
-- @column would be "`color`,`date`" for the example table in our question.
--
SET @columns = (
  SELECT
    REPLACE(REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('`', COLUMN_NAME, '`')), '`id`,', ''), ',`id`', '')
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table_name' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = (SELECT DATABASE())
);

--
-- Build a SQL query string @sql according to @columns
--
SET @sql = CONCAT(
  'INSERT INTO `table_name_new` (',
  @columns,
  ') SELECT ',
  @columns,
  ' FROM `table_name` ORDER BY date;'
);

--
-- Prepare and execute the SQL statement
--
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;
```

Comment: Is it possible that you confused table_name and table_name_new, since I actually want to Insert into the new one?

Comment: Btw, your solution works perfectly when I switch the table names. I hoped for a general solution where I didn't have to write down all column names, since there are quite a few in the actual original table, but nevermind. Once you corrected your post, I can approve it.

Comment: @DanielM: Added way to build the column list automatically with MySQL.